# How to Run Ktor Embedded Server from Code

Tags: kotlin, server, ktor

I've written a simple Ktor server that processes a JSON payload from an incoming POST request. Now, I want to spawn this server from another application, and after processing the request, shut it down.

So the first problem I need to solve is: how do I spawn the Ktor server from some other 'driver' Kotlin code? All the tutorials I've found online are 1-2 years old, and are apparently using an older version of Ktor, where the main class looks like this:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText("Hello from Kotlin Backend", ContentType.Text.Html)
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

It's easy to see that one can just run the `embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) { ... }.start(wait = true)` from wherever they want, to spawn the server. But I downloaded the Ktor plugin for IntelliJ IDEA yesterday, and it seems things have changed lately. This is what the new main class looks like:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

@Suppress("unused") // Referenced in application.conf
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson {
        }
    }

    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("HELLO WORLD!", contentType = ContentType.Text.Plain)
        }

        get("/json/gson") {
            call.respond(mapOf("hello" to "world"))
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the `Application.module(...)` function takes care of setting up the routing and stuff, while the actual running of the server is done internally by `io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)`. Also, properties like the port number are referenced from the `application.conf` file, and I'm not quite sure how it figures out where to find that `application.conf` file.

I have been able to run this Ktor server using `gradlew`. I also understand that it is possible to export it as an executable jar and run it (as explained [here](https://ktor.io/servers/deploy/packing/fatjar.html)). But I can't find out how to run it from code. Any suggestions?

Edit: And it would be nice if I could set the port number from the driver code.

Comment: It looks like the issue is relative to where resources are placed on Android. I'm not familiar with where this would be, but have you tried placing them there?

Comment: @HadiHariri Actually, I'm trying to run this server from an IntelliJ plugin.

Comment: @HadiHariri Anyway, I combined the Ktor and the IntelliJ plugins/dependencies into one `build.gradle` file. I then placed the `application.conf` in the `src/main/resources` folder and added `main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']` to the `sourceSets` in the `build.gradle` file. When I ran everything, I get the the error `No configuration provided`.